# How to edit a clipping mask that is a smart object - Photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, creative-cloud, clipping-mask

Created a clipping mask using a smart object. I was wondering if I wanted to add or subtract to the clipping mask would I have to rasterise it first?

[image]

Comment: You can double click a Smart Object in the layers panel, to open and edit it.